# ORA-21500: internal error code, arguments: [%s], [%s], [%s], [%s], [%s], [%s], [%s], [%s]

Tags: c#, .net, oracle, oracle11g

I searched a lot but none of the links helped me in resolving this issue. I am getting

> ORA-21500: internal error code, arguments: [%s], [%s], [%s], [%s],
>   [%s], [%s], [%s], [%s] when using OracleDataAdapter.

I am using 11.2.0 Oracle client and the oracle dataset is 11.1.0.7.0. Can anyone please help me in why I am getting this error? Some of the links that I searched say it is due to incompatible oracle client and database. This error is intermittent and debugging the issue didn't give much clue.

Result StackTrace:

```
at Oracle.DataAccess.Client.OracleException.HandleErrorHelper(Int32 errCode, OracleConnection conn, IntPtr opsErrCtx, OpoSqlValCtx* pOpoSqlValCtx, Object src, String procedure, Boolean bCheck)
at Oracle.DataAccess.Client.OracleDataReader.Read()
at System.Data.Common.DataAdapter.FillLoadDataRow(SchemaMapping mapping)
at System.Data.Common.DataAdapter.FillFromReader(DataSet dataset, DataTable datatable, String srcTable, DataReaderContainer dataReader, Int32 startRecord, Int32 maxRecords, DataColumn parentChapterColumn, Object parentChapterValue)
at System.Data.Common.DataAdapter.Fill(DataTable[] dataTables, IDataReader dataReader, Int32 startRecord, Int32 maxRecords)
at Oracle.DataAccess.Client.OracleDataAdapter.Fill(DataTable[] dataTables, Int32 startRecord, Int32 maxRecords, IDbCommand command, CommandBehavior behavior)
at System.Data.Common.DbDataAdapter.Fill(DataTable dataTable)
```

Answer (score 2):

Thanks for the comment. I just found that this problem is due to the fetch size that I am setting on the Oracle command object from which I am creating Oracle Data Adaptor. As soon as I stopped setting the command fetch size, it started working fine without any issues.

Answer (score 1):

From [here](http://support.esri.com/en/knowledgebase/techarticles/detail/33918):

> **Cause**
>
> The cause of the error is an internal Oracle error which neither
>   ArcGIS nor ArcSDE can control. The error is encountered when the
>   application generates a SQL statement using an asterisk in the SELECT
>   list (SELECT * FROM...).
>
> For further information on the Oracle error please see Oracle's
>   Metalink Note:49375.1.
>
> **Workaround**
>
> There are two possible workarounds for this issue. Ensure there is a
>   spatial index present for the feature class and/or add an additional
>   attribute after the ST_Geometry attribute.
>
> To verify if a spatial index is present, using ArcCatalog, connect to
>   the ArcSDE instance as the feature class owner. Select the feature
>   class. Open the properties dialog box. Select the indexes tab and
>   verify that the spatial index is present.
>
> To add a new attribute to a feature class in ArcCatalog, open the
>   feature class properties. Select the fields tab and add the new
>   attribute.
>
> Once the ST_Geometry attribute is no longer in the last position of
>   the SELECT * list, the internal ORA-21500 error is no longer
>   encountered.